# C++ environment recommendation?

Tags: c++, ide

I´m a completely newbie and i like to know which environment can you recommend me for programming in C++, i mean Operating System (if Linux, Ubuntu is a right option?), IDE, etc. maybe i have to create a virtual machine?

Comment: Linux CLI with emacs and g++.

Comment: Any question you can tag with [tag:recommendations] is off-topic on SO.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Imagine a stranger comes to you with the question "Should I marry a blonde or a brunette"? First determine what do you want with C++, what do you need it for?

Comment: @Seth, let me fix that typo for you: "Linux CLI with vi and g++" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo it makes me thankful you can't edit someone's comment like you can their answer :)

Comment: @Dialecticus - I think it is pretty clear from the question that he is a newbie that would like to learn C++... For that, I'd assume just any recommendation of a friendly environment will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is easily one of the most elegant environments, because it has a sane policy for handling packages and versions and libraries and include paths.

Basically, you can install a compiler and any common development library with a single clean command (e.g. `aptitude install libpng-dev`), and everything is taken care of. You can also install any number of build systems (`make`, autotools, `cmake`, ...), and they're immediately available without any further setup.

Most importantly, Linux is build around being able to compile source, so literally almost every executable in the system is load-time linked against the C (and possibly C++) standard libraries, which are shipped with the distribution.

Windows by comparison has none of those features. There is *no* all-purpose, system-wide runtime library, so everything you compile has to be carefully set up and crafted into a special build environment. Moreover, almost any terminal emulator I know for Linux is by far faster than any Windows console. You also have text manipulation tools (`less`, `grep`, `find`) readily available in Linux. Finally, there are great editors (Emacs, Vi), and there's `valgrind`.

Comment: This is a really great answer, +1. I'm going to bookmark this page for it.

Comment: Thank you all, for your answers and most important for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`CodeBlocks` is great free and opensource

Comment: i check this one right now, thank you.